# Update a JSON column with WHERE Clause in JSON Column Postgres

Tags: postgresql, json

I am having trouble writing a `WHERE` clause to update a JSON column in Postgres database:

Given a table of the form:

```sql
create table Test_Table (
    clusterId INT, 
    owner VARCHAR(50), 
    data JSONB
)
```

And three rows of data:

```
insert into Test_Table
values
(1, 'Jacky',{data}),
(2, 'Bob', NULL), 
(3, 'Wolf',NULL);
```

...where the `{data}` in row 1 is a json document of the form...

```
{
    "certified": [
        {
            "Type": "New Instance",
            "Status": "Active",
            "created": "2020-02-03",
            "id_no": "f6b2197c4889"
        },
        {
            "Type": "New Instance",
            "Status": "Failed",
            "created": "2020-02-04",
            "id_no": "216430036272"
        },
        {
            "Type": "New Instance",
            "Status": "Active",
            "created": "2020-02-04",
            "id_no": "3bb515f781c6"
        },
        {
            "Type": "New Instance",
            "Status": "Active",
            "created": "2020-02-04",
            "id_no": "26ae740e9b21"
        },
        {
            "Type": "New Instance",
            "Status": "Active",
            "created": "2020-02-04",
            "id_no": "7e30a80211a2"
        }
    ],
    "in_common": [
        {
            "name": "Kodali",
            "owner": "Jet"
        },
        {
            "name": "Lakers",
            "owner": "Fantastic"
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to write an update statement to update the `data` column and change the `"Status"` to `'Active'` where `cluster_id` is 1 and `"id_no"` is "216430036272". How do I write a `WHERE` clause that will update only this attribute?

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model. In this case you must unnest the array elements, change the ones you want and the aggregate everything back into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, this would be a much easier task if the data was properly normalised. However, in the interest of wasting a morning playing with [postgres json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), you could use the following query ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b0a03e025654a407a088a08b2c4101fb))

```sql
with js as (
    select 
        jsonb_array_elements((data->>'certified')::jsonb) as elems
    from test_table
    where clusterid = 1
), to_keep as (
    select elems
    from js
    where js.elems->>'id_no' != '216430036272'
), to_upd as (
    select
        jsonb_set(elems,'{Status}','"Active"') as elems
    from js
    where js.elems->>'id_no' = '216430036272'
), final_array as (
    select jsonb_agg(elems) as elems
    from (
        select elems from to_keep
        union all 
        select elems from to_upd
    ) j
)
update test_table set 
    data = jsonb_set(data,'{certified}',elems)
from final_array fa
where clusterid = 1;
```

---

Pretty clearly this is very specifically answering your narrow question, so you'll need to make your own modifications to generalise it. By way of a breakdown though...

> I want to ... update the `data` column and change the `"Status"` to "Active" where `"cluster_id"` is 1 and `"id_no"` is "216430036272"

#### `js`

```sql
select 
    jsonb_array_elements((data->>'certified')::jsonb) as elems
from test_table
where clusterid = 1
```

The first [common table expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) filters down to `clusterid = 1` out of all the rows in `Test_Table`

The element `certified` in your json document is itself an array of objects - as indicated by the `[{},{}]` notation. For this reason, you need to unwrap the array. `jsonb_array_elements` turns a single row into many rows. Thus the cell...

```
+---------+
| array   |
+---------+
| [{},{}] |
+---------+
```

...becomes...

```
+---------+
| objects |
+---------+
| {}      |
| {}      |
+---------+
```

#### `to_keep`

Now that you've unwrapped the objects in the array, you need to preserve them. This CTE isolates those objects that you **do not** want to modify (`js.elems->>'id_no' != '216430036272'`) so that they can be re-aggregated unchanged into the array later.

#### `to_upd`

This is the object you've stated you want to update (specified by `js.elems->>'id_no' = '216430036272'`). `jsonb_set(elems,'{Status}','"Active"')` modifies the `Status` element as desired (case sensitive).

#### `final_array`

```sql
select jsonb_agg(elems) as elems
from (
    select elems from to_keep
    union all 
    select elems from to_upd
) j
```

You need to turn many rows back into one row to re-create the array-of-objects you decomposed to perform the update in the first place. [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) re-connects the rowsets from `to_keep` and `to_upd` and then `jsonb_agg` causes

```
+---------+
| objects |
+---------+
| {}      |
| {}      |
+---------+
```

...to turn back into...

```
+---------+
| array   |
+---------+
| [{},{}] |
+---------+
```

...which allows us to use it in...

#### The actual `UPDATE` statement

```sql
update test_table set 
    data = jsonb_set(data,'{certified}',elems)
from final_array fa
where clusterid = 1;
```

You must re-specify `clusterid = 1` in order to target the correct row for modification. `jsonb_set` is seen here again, this time supplanting the entire `certified` node with the reconstructed data from `final_array.elems`

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. This answers my question.